# Can't get Scrapy spider_opened to be called

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to check to see if a file is locked when my spider opens. I can't get the signal to fire. Here is my code thus far:

```
from scrapy import signals

class MySpider(Spider):

    @staticmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):

        spider = MySpider.from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return spider

    def spider_opened(self):
        if lockFile(self.name + ".lock"):
        sys.exit()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: from_crawler() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Why are you using `@staticmethod`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static methods do not receive the class as the first argument, in fact there is no additional argument supplied. Remove `cls` and it should correct the error.

```
@staticmethod
def from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    ....
```

**Update**

[`from_crawler()`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#from_crawler) should be a class method, not a static method:

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks! That error disappeared but now I get another error: `Unhandled error in Deferred:
2018-05-28 17:23:28 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Temporarily disabling observer LegacyLogObserverWrapper(<bound method PythonLoggingObserver.emit of <twisted.python.log.PythonLoggingObserver object at 0x10bc07a90>>) due to exception: [Failure instance: Traceback: <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Comment: Actually, it seems that `from_crawler()` should be a class method. Try using `@classmethod` instead of `@staticmethod` (and put `cls` back into the argument list). See update.

Comment: Thanks mhawke that worked. I needed to add a few other snippets to finish the solution but your suggesting got me most of the way there.